# How can I rename uploaded files?

Tags: 8, files, wysiwyg

Using Drupal 8, I want to rename and clean all the uploaded filenames. I want to convert all the spaces to dashes and make all the characters lowercase. A file named *Screen Shot 2016-03-29 at 1.13.21 PM.jpg* would become *screen-shot-2016-03-29-at-1.13.21-pm.jpg*.

I want to do this on the image upload dialog form used by CkEditor.

Comment: Try https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths

Comment: `filefield_paths` works only for fields attached to content types. I want similar solution for inline images.

Comment: Try one of the working patches on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2492171). Look at [the answer to this similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246761/file-name-transliteration/247315#247315). Use a test installation or backup before trying to patch Drupal core. (If it works well for you, you will probably need to patch the core at every core update, unless this option is making it into Drupal 8.5.)

Comment: Curently is not possible using core to transliterate uploaded filenames (referer to [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2492171) and [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3032390) core issues). To solve this you need to use the [Transliterate filenames for uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliterate_filenames) module. Check the comments from above.

Comment: You can use the [File rename](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_rename) module Good luck