# File name transliteration

Tags: 8, transliteration

I need to clean up file names on upload. Both for image fields, other file fields and IMCE file manager. The [transliteration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) is not yet ported to Drupal 8 and the community [does not seem to agree](https://www.drupal.org/node/2492171) on how to implement the core transliteration in Drupal 8.

Do I have to make a [custom module](https://www.buzzwoo.de/blog/better-filename-transliteration-drupal-8-transliteration-using-non-default-language) for this, or is there a simpler way?

Right now, Drupal 8 seems to allow both spaces and special characters in filenames. I know about the module [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths), but it will have to be set up for every file field on every content type. I don't think it will work with IMCE.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the module [already mentioned](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/270522/94847) is now covered by Drupals security advisory policy:

**Transliterate filenames for uploads** - https://www.drupal.org/project/transliterate_filenames

> Stable releases for this project are covered by the security advisory policy.
>
> **8.x-1.3 Stable release** covered by the Drupal Security Team released 1 July 2019

Answer (score 2):

I applied a Drupal 8 core patch from [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2492171). It seems to work fine. It adds a new option to `/admin/config/media/file-system`:
[image: File transliteration option Drupal 8]

This option enables transliteration for all future uploads to all file fields. It also works for inline images when `Enable image uploads` is enabled (for the text-format). I don't know if the patch affects IMCE, since IMCE was not installed on my test installation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that https://www.drupal.org/project/transliterate_filenames

> Transliteration for all uploading files (includes fields and ckeditor
>   inline upload)
>
> How to use: just enable module as usual. All new file names will be
>   transliterate to Latin characters.

Comment: This project is not covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy.

Comment: The module is stable now and it works: 1.It replaces spaces in file names 2.Adds a counter for duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this module.
This module is based on the blog post by [Alexander Belov](https://www.buzzwoo.de/blog/better-filename-transliteration-drupal-8-transliteration-using-non-default-language), but simplified for a less specific use case.
https://drupal.org/project/filename_transliteration