# Private File Permissions Not Working for a Single file - Can't Identify where to find error

Tags: nodes, files

I have the following set up:

- Private file field configured on content type
- Access control configured with referenced user having permission to view file
- If user is referenced on the node, they can view the private file of that node.

Here is the issue that I am having:

- A specific file could not be loaded. Drupal Redirects as if the user does not have proper permissions to view the file.
- Other files, with an identical setup work fine
- If I download the file, rename it and re-upload to a new node, it works
- If I download the file, rename it and then re-upload on the original node it works

So, I have an intermittent issue where a tiny subset of files are not able to viewed by the user.  What could possibly cause a single node/file combo to fail as described above?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the symbols of the file name. Probably, when PHP do the `file_exists` - it may get false because the file is not 'visible'.
Try this https://www.drupal.org/project/transliterate_filenames or similar modules to transliterate the filenames during the uploads.

See more here [File name transliteration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246761/file-name-transliteration)